# How to put more than 64k in one SEGMENT in MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm, memory-segmentation

I have tried using `.model huge` but still I'm getting this error:

```
A2103: Segment Exceeds 64k limit
```

How do you use more than 64k in a segment?
I'm using MASM for 8086

Comment: MASM and emu8086 are two separate assemblers.  EMU8086 is an all-in-one editor + assembler + simulator + debugger.  Your error message looks like it's actually from MASM so I fixed your tags.

Comment: See e.g. https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/073/Q73187/ The 16-bit hardware only supports 64K segments. Huge means that data structures potentially span several segments. The implementation of huge segments has to be done by the programmer. You would define several 64K segments beside each other and update the respective segment register, when accessing the data.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have more than 64k in a segment. But since you're using `.model huge` you can have more segments than just `.data` and `.code`. I'm not too familiar with MASM syntax but you should be able to do something like:

```
extraStuff segment

   ; put whatever you want here.

extraStuff ends
```

That should give you another 64k of memory to use.

Now, if you're trying to read/write to some array that spans multiple segments you'll have to know when to stop, load the next segment and continue on. If you're doing something like `lodsb`, and `si` crosses from `ffff` to `0000` it won't increment `ds` to the next segment, it just wraps around (I believe.)